# How to set fullCalendar event draggable containment is body?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, fullcalendar

[In the picture you can see the event can able to drag outside the screen , is there any way to prevent the overflow, Click me for preview, Please help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XEx3.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please visit the help centre and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you mean.

You should be able to simply apply `overflow-x: hidden;` to the `body` element in the CSS.

So it'll look like this:

```
body {
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

It's hard to know what the issue is without a working example to test though.